What is the lowest viable circular orbit around Mars that can last at least one week?
Supposing you wanted to launch a spaceship from the surface of Mars into orbit around Mars.  It would stay in orbit for up to one week while you prepared a second rocket that would dock with it to transfer fuel.  After transferring fuel, the second rocket would land, and the first rocket would fly away from Mars.
In the absence of atmosphere, to have a circular orbit, you just need gravity = velocity^2/orbit_radius.  So, in that case, radiuses all the way to the ground are valid solutions mathematically.
So, this questions probably comes down to atmospheric drag as the limiting factor.

The Martian atmosphere is like 2% as dense as Earth's at ground level, so one would expect that the lowest possible orbital height is much less than that of Earth.

Mars' gravity is only 3.71m/s^2 at ground level.  So with less gravity the atmosphere spreads out more vertically, which would tend to increase the minimum required orbital height.


What is the lowest viable circular orbit around Mars that can last at least one week?
"Last one week" means that the ship doesn't fall to the ground, but its altitude may decrease a bit.

The rate of decrease of the atmospheric pressure is governed by the scale height, but that's affected by temperature.

@PM2Ring and average atomic/molecular mass and the expression breaks down above the turbopause Now the questions are 1) which of all those effects in those answers happen above or below the altitude for which the lifetime is one week, and 2) will his be for a quiet Sun or an active Sun?

Is the orbiting object more like a LAGEOS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAGEOS or an Echo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Echo ?

Mars freezes over a quarter of its atmosphere at the south pole in the winter, so the answer varies with time of year, too.

@PM2Ring I found this https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/atmosmrm.html but the temperature drops below absolute zero at the relevant altitudes so it's not useful. One can request the Mars Global Reference Atmospheric Model 2010 (Mars GRAM 2010) which is "...widely used for diverse mission applications, including systems design, performance analysis, and operations planning for aerobraking, entry descent and landing, and aerocapture." NTRS 20140003184

@PM2Ring next, generate a density vs height table for "summer" and "winter" extremes, then a simple 2D ODE solver starting at an array of altitudes, propagating for one week. I am sure the problem can be reduced to 1D using the vis-viva equation and assuming circularity, that won't be invalid until the very last moments when it doesn't really matter anyway. (I tried to create a guest account for the software download, but it's giving me trouble)
